# Writing to JSON column of Postgres database using Spring / JPA

Tags: json, spring, jpa, postgresql-9.3

I have a table called "test" containing a column "sample_column" of type json in Postgres 9.3. I'm trying to write the following contents into the column using Spring / JPA: {"name":"Updated name"}

I read on other posts that I need to add a custom converter to map the string to json type. This is the code I have now:

TestDAO.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class TestDAO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;   

    @Column(name="sample_column")
    @Convert(converter = MyCustomConverter.class)
    private MyCustomClass sampleColumn;

    // Getter / Setters
}
```

The CustomClass for mapping the json content:

```
public class MyCustomClass {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And finally, the ConverterClass:

```
@javax.persistence.Converter
public class MyCustomConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyCustomClass, String> {

    private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(@NotNull MyCustomClass myCustomObject) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myCustomObject);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public MyCustomClass convertToEntityAttribute(@NotNull String databaseDataAsJSONString) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(databaseDataAsJSONString, MyCustomClass.class);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to set the json column as follows:

```
testDAO.getSampleColumn().setName("Updated name");
testRepository.saveAndFlush(testDAO);
```

But when I try to save it, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "sample_column" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

However, I am able to read the JSON column using `testDAO.getSampleColumn().getName();`
What is the problem here? I do not want to add any cast to the table for converting Varying to Json automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your JPA provider and specification?  Are you certain that your provider is JPA 2.1 compliant?  Converters require JPA 2.1.

Comment: A similar question has been answered. Find the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47550896/9729935

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need to either use `setObject` at the JDBC level, or pass the PgJDBC parameter `stringtype=unspecified` to allow implicit casts from string types to `json` etc.

It's a problem with PostgreSQL being too strict about type casting.

Comment: Where should I be using `setObject()`? Sorry, I'm new to JPA. Can you provide some sample code? Or at least point me to some resources?

Comment: @drunkenfist You probably have to write a custom type handler for the underlying persistence implementation like Hibernate. I suggest using the jdbc driver parameter instead.

Comment: I'm using Spring-boot, where I set all DB properties in application.properties file. Is there a specific property I can use to set `stringtype=unspecified`? Right now, I'm just adding it as a param to `spring.datasource.url` (i.e) `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname?stringtype=unspecified`. Doing this works. But I do not want to add it to the datasource url. I would prefer if it was a separate property.

Comment: @drunkenfist That depends on spring boot really. If it offers you access to other jdbc driver options like 'user' and 'password' you should be able to set it in the same place.

Comment: Ok, looks like Spring-boot offers a `spring.datasource.connection-properties` which we can use to add any additional parameters. Thank you.

Comment: Very good answer, especially together with the comments. I would like to see the answer extended with the information from the comments.

Comment: What holds me back from doing this: What are the downsides? I'm sure this setting has many, probably undesired, side effects.

Comment: few actually. possibly some increased risk of failure to resolve overloaded functions. not much else.

Comment: `spring.datasource.connection-properties` [no longer works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250678/set-jpa-utf-8-encoding-in-application-properties/40255073#comment67774997_40255073). This one works for me: `spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties`

Comment: Im confused. How do I pass the PgJDBC parameter `stringtype=unspecified`? Do I set it in my model class like this: `@Column(name = "blob") @Convert(stringtype=json) private String blob;`

Comment: @StephenKuehl It's a JDBC connection parameter, for the JDBC URL.

Comment: The DB URL trick works, while Spring boot properties does not. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

For people using Spring-boot there are two ways to do what @Craig Ringer said

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified
```

or using properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.stringtype=unspecified
```

Answer (score 3):

Though both works, I suggest use the PGobject feature rather setting the feature at the connection level.

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PGobject languageObject = new PGobject();
languageObject.setType("json");
languageObject.setValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(blogPosts.getLanguages()));
```

Once done, pass the params to the Spring jdbctemplate to do the magic

Hope this.

Comment: Is there any way to use this approach within `convertToDatabaseColumn()` as per the author's question? I'm new to JPA and have been struggling with a similar issue. If I just blindly put this in `convertToDatabaseColumn` Postgres starts complaining about `bytea` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your JSON to String and then create a PGobject out of it. This solution works for me:

```
PGobject pGobject = new PGobject();
pGobject.setType("json");
pGobject.setValue(vehicleJsonData);

    try {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_CREATE, Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setLong(1, id);
            ps.setObject(2, pGobject);
            return ps;
        }, keyHolder);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```