# inserting json string from spring application into postgres jsonb

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I want to insert json string, which has no predefined structure i.e. key value formats are not fixed, into a postgres column with `jsonb` datatype. My application uses HikariCP alongwith JPA.

Earlier I had the following generic cast operation in postgres to achieve the above but its not recommended by my DBA as it fundamentally alters the varchar datatype.

```
CREATE CAST (character varying AS jsonb) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

While looking for application side alternatives, I came across setting stringtype as unspecified like below

```
spring:   
  profiles: development   
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/mydb
    username: my_user
    password: 'my_password'
    hikari:
      auto-commit: true
      maximumPoolSize: 2
      leakDetectionThreshold: 60000
    tomcat:
      connection-properties: stringtype=unspecified
```

The above configuration doesn't help. connection-properties doesn't seem to be a direct property of datasource. Various answers on forums just tell you to set stringtype=unspecified in connection-properties but a clear working answer would be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While thinking about it, I realized that this property must be set HikariCP. When I looked through various parameters it allows me to set, I came across data-source-properties. Following is what I discovered as the solution to above problem

```
hikari:
  data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified
```

Comment: For those who are looking for the flattened version `spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.stringtype=unspecified`

Comment: this is good for json, but for me breaks LIKE query with emty parameters as side effect